# Why is the ring at such an angle when animated?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

So I was doing a ring attached to chains... I've been helped before and decided to start over again... however this time when I animate by alt+a this happened: the ring stays at this angle... I've included the blend file... any help would be appreciated... thx

And also...can someone tell me how to increase the preview animation in the timeline (so that its longer than 250 frames) setting the end frame to 300 doesn't animate it further than 250... it's like the 50 frames were never there...

[image]

Here is the file: [image]

Comment: Please read the following link: [why is it important to apply transformations](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7298/1853)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To not to have any issues with **Rigid Body Simulation** remember to always apply **Scale and Rotation** for your objects - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and also keep in mind that really small objects will behave strangely.

In your case, after applying **Scale and Rotation** you will need to change ring **Mass** to something like 1.

Secondly, to increase **Rigid Body Simulation** time you will need to go to **Scene tab** and under **Rigid Body Cache** set the **End** value to match your **Timeline** value.

[image: scenr]

Comment: ty for the answer...it helped